# Does the following series converge? If so, is it transcendental?

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Let $RF_n(x)$ be a recursive factorial function defined by

$RF_0(x) =x$

$RF_1(x)=x!$

$RF_{n+1}(x)=RF_n(x)!$

ie,

$RF_n(1) = 1 \space  \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

$RF_n(2) = 2 \space \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

$RF_0(3) = 3$

$RF_1(3) = 3! = 6$

$RF_2(3) =(3!)! = 720$

Let $D_n(x)$ be a function that moves the place of the decimal point of any real number to the left of its highest power significant place by n if its highest significant power is odd, to the left of its highest significant power by $(n-1)!$ if its highest significant power is even.

ie,

$D_1(120) = .120$

$D_1(.0725)= .725$

$D_2(1234.5678)=.012345678$

$D_2(4321)=.4321$

Does the series $J_n =\sum_0^n D_{i+1}(RF_i(3))$
converge as $n \to \infty$?

An initial approximation for the first three terms show:

$J_3 = .3 + .6 + .072=.972$

If it converges, is it an irrational number? If it is irrational, is it transcendental?

If the answer to those questions are not available, does anyone know what research there is on computationally dense convergence?

Comment: What do you mean by highest significant power?  It is the same as the leftmost nonzero digit?  Would $D_3(4321)=.04321$ because the $4$ is even and we want the decimal $(3-1)!$ places left of $4$ and $D_3(1234)=.001234$ because $1$ is odd and we want the decimal $3$ places left of the $1$?

Comment: I didn't get it, do you mean $RF_0(n) = n$ and $RF_{k+1}(n) = RF_k(n)!$ ?

Comment: @RossMillikan if you understood such an impossible to understand question, you should start by defining it in simple rigorous words (it is how you'll help him)

Comment: @user1952009:  I believe your definition of $RF_k$ is correct.  I took a guess for $D_k$ and hope OP will clarify.

Comment: @RossMillikan My apologies, the fault in the language is clearly mine. As I wrote the question it was with the interpretation of representing real numbers as a polynomial sum $\sum{a_i10^i}$ and meant to define the function as an operation that manipulates the first nonzero coefficient. I realize now that I should have been clearer with my wording of the question. And yes, your interpretation of the function is correct.

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, that is what I meant to define by recursive polynomial. My apologies for the inefficient wording of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming my interpretation of $D_n$ is correct, the sum converges.  For $i \gt 3, D_{i+1}(RF_i(3)) \lt 10^{-i}$ and all the terms are positive, so we have an increasing sequence with an upper bound.  It is undoubtedly transcentental, because almost all reals are, but I suspect a proof will not be available.